# How to format the URL of .html page to remove extension with .htaccess? (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, redirect

So I have a custom created .html page in my website's root folder (along with WP) and I want to be able to open it in a standard Wordpress URL format, in other words without the .html extension at the end.

Bear in mind I know nothing about regular expressions or .htaccess, so I will give you concrete example:

When I type in  `mydomain.com/specialpage`  I want it to load `mydomain.com/specialpage.html`, but keep the originally typed URL format (without extension)

Comment: An alternative, without modifying .htaccess, is to make a directory called  `specialpage`, and then have your file as the index.html inside of that directory.

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(specialpage)/?$ /$1.html [L,NC]
```

This appears to be working. Just had to put it above other default rules Wordpress came with.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple pages, you can do it like this instead:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

# Check to see if a .html file exists for this request.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/$ # Prevent internal recursion

# If so, then use serve that file.
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

> A note about trailing slashes: You won't be able to do that here, as it will include it in the request filename, thus checking to see if `specialpage/.html` exists, which is not what you want.